# ruby on rails variable to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am calling a controller action from a view like this:

```
<%= link_to "cancel offer", offermethod_offer_path, 
    class: "btn btn-medium btn-danger pull-right"  %>
```

The controller action deletes a record (offer). I use the params[:id] tag from the page to identify the record in the controller like this:

```
class OffersController < ApplicationController
   def offermethod
      Offer.find(params[:id]).destroy
   end
.
end
```

However, I would like to pass an additional parameter to the offermethod. Can I pass an instance variable from the offer view, so the code would look something like

```
<%= link_to "cancel offer", offermethod_offer_path(@variable.id), 
    class: "btn btn-medium btn-danger pull-right"  %>
```

and in the controller

```
   def offermethod(variable)
      Offer.find(variable).destroy
   end
```

I have tried to do this but I can't pass the variable/id parameter. Get the error like 'cannot find offer with nil id'.

Can you help me with the correct way to pass the variable to the controller like this? Many thanks!

Comment: how about `<%= link_to "cancel offer", offermethod_offer_path(@variable), 
    class: "btn btn-medium btn-danger pull-right"  %>`  then in your controller, `def offermethod  Offer.find(params[:offer]).destroy end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. However, you need to name the variable, as GET params are key/value pairs.

`<%= link_to "cancel offer", offermethod_offer_path(name: @variable.id), #...`

A cleaner approach would be to just add a member route to your collection, like

```
resources :offers do 
  delete :offermethod, on: :member
end
```

This way, you can use a simple `Offer.find params[:id]`, like @sircapsalot may wants to say.

**edit**:
I don't know, but I feel like you should read the rails guides, especially the parts about REST and the HTTP verbs. If you delete/destroy a resource, you should use a `DELETE` type http request, as I have described the route above. However, you also need to pass the desired method to your form or your link. For a link, this would be `link_to 'name', path_to_object_delete_method(object), method: :delete`. The same thing counts for a form.

Comment: thanks, this looks perfect I will test it tomorrow and get back.  may use member as well but I want to be able to call the action from many pages so will lose the id param

Comment: Hi there - a follow up question. Can I grab fields from the page, like text input boxes? Normally I would have to use a form for this but I wonder if there's a way to do it without using form_for. Because form_for always sends to the create/update actions, and I want to use a different action. Or alternatively, is there a way to use form_for but specify the controller action?

Comment: `form_for` does not always send to a create/update action. You just specify `method: :get` and give an `url:` with a path to the action your form `GET`'s to. Or you use javascript to collect your data and append it to the GET request when your user clicks the link.

Comment: ok so I have made something that works, but it is a hacked-together piece of crap... I'm within a controller called firms but I am passing params in the url because couldn't get the variable to work, got error wrong method for this class type. Link code is to remove a member from a network - <%= link_to "remove", "rufn?userid=#{network_user.user_id}" %> - and then I read the params from the relevant controller

Comment: Actually I am not deleting a record, changing its status to false, but you are right, I should read the rails guides